# Forcing Image Size through HTML Table

Tags: html, image

I'm wondering how I can accomplish this above (using only HTML or inline CSS with HTML). I'm really looking at setting up something as simple has a photo grid (I'm assuming a table would be best to do this) of 3 images wide and however many images I need in length.

Here is a preview of what I'm trying to do for my church's new website: https://web.archive.org/web/20160115182724/http://kindredchurch.org/im-new/leadership/

We have taken some new photos and would like to make it so that all my images are locked to a specific size I tell it to be. Is this possible?

Comment: Why dont you use heigth and width attributes of img if you want it to be in a specific size....

Comment: Could you show me what this would look like?

Comment: There are very many ways to accomplish this. What have you done so far? Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: Like <td> <img src="something.jpg" height="45" width="60"/></td> ... width and height in pixels

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem for you? If so, please close the question *by clicking checkmark beside answer to select it as Best Answer.* Otherwise, please add a comment below my answer so we can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

Using tables isn't the way to go about this. You need to use Divs within divs within divs. Divs are boxes into which you put... everything.

There's a little more to this than you might have realized. For example, what about differently-sized screens? How about phones? How do you make the images / structure resize appropriately?

Wouldn't it be great if there was a table-like structure that would allow you to easily cover off those possibilities?

It's called Bootstrap.

Run through [this 30-minute example project](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) and you'll have an excellent start.

Then, look up some YouTube tutorials on Bootstrap if you need more info. But using tables for formatting will just bring you long-term grief.

---

Background: CSS is the styling that sets the font *size*, the font *color*, the margin widths, element height -- that sort of thing.

You can add CSS to the content in multiple ways. Most common is via an external CSS file (not good for you) or between `<style></style>` tags - which might work for you. It looks like this:

```html
<style>
  #bigBox{margin:50px;padding:50px;background:yellow;border:1px solid maroon;}
  #innerBox{padding:30px;font-size:2rem;color:darkcyan;background:wheat;border:1px solid orange;}
  .slantMe{font-style:italic;color:red;}
</style>

<div id="bigBox">
  <div id="innerBox">
    This box <span class="slantMe">styled</span> by CSS
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can see how the above example keeps the styling instructions *separate* from the HTML. Nice and clean and easy to read.

Alternately, though, you can use the very same CSS by adding a `style="css:value;"` *attribute* on any HTML tag. For example, the above would be:

```html
<div id="bigBox" style="margin:50px;padding:50px;background:yellow;border:1px solid maroon;">
  <div style="padding:30px;font-size:2rem;color:darkcyan;background:wheat;border:1px solid orange;">
    This is <span style="font-style:italic;color:red;">messier,</span> but works!
  </div>
</div>
```

HTML tags can have several different ***attributes*** inside the tag, depending on the type of tag. For example:

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="get">  <-- action/method are specific to form tag

<textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea> <-- rows/cols specific to textarea tag

<p style="font-weight:bold;color:green;">Some stuff </p> <-- most tags can have style attribute
```

A new attribute worth knowing about is [the `data` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). It's an attribute that lets you store hidden information in the tag itself! I didn't see any obvious use/purpose for you from this question, but it's good to know about. *Might be useful in the future, who knows?*

Comment: This seems fantastic. I actually have used divs before, it's just been a long time since I've had to code anything with HTML and divs have slipped my mind! :) I'm going to try this out right now and get back to you!

Comment: Looking over this, it seems it requires CSS as well, or am I reading that incorrectly? Because I can only use HTML in the CMS we're using.

Comment: See update to my answer. I probably shouldn't have added the extra unnecessary bit about data attributes, but *they're cool...*